# Default Input Language in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, regional-settings

I have this situation: the computer, that is running windows 10 is using Russian as the system language, but I don't want to have Russian input method enabled for the computer.

When the system language is set to Russian, it doesn't allow to remove the keyboard layout for Russian; if I add other language, the only way to remove the Russian is by changing the system language.

How can I remove an input method, that is set as system language ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you add multiple keyboards, you should be able to change the default to something different. Once changed, you should be able to remove the old default keyboard though possibly not recommended in case someone really needs to type in Russian.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Julian Knight, but even I have multiple languages enabled as input methods, I can't remove the default language (Russian), if I try to change the default to another language, after computer restart the system language changes to the other language. I have done the same on windows 7, but couldn't manage on windows 10. Have You tried this on windows 10 specifically ?